# Magento2: How to create different home page

Tags: magento2

1) Case 1: I need to create different Homepage Pages for each store views. So I have multiple store view and after enable page builder when I finished build page then display the same page on each store view.

How to set different home page for each store?

I have found information:

2) Case 2: if store view B, you want different something with store view A, you also use IMPORT and EXPORT but before IMPORT to store view B, you must create another CMS page first and assign it to store view B in **STORES >> Configuration >> Web [GENERAL]** then go to **admin MGS >> Theme Setting, select store view B then IMPORT the homepage you just EXPORTED.** In this case because you created another CMS page for store view B, so you can enable the builder on store view B then edit it and your changes will only affect to store view B.

but before IMPORT to store view B, you must create another cms page first and assign it to store view B in **STORES >> Configuration >> Web [GENERAL]**

- OK, but how to create another CMS page? I should first go to **content >> Pages** and then create new pages and copy from 'home' eg. to 'home2' and then set in **STORES >> Configuration >> Web [GENERAL]**?

[image]

@ UPDATE

1) in Content >> Pages I have create new page "home2"

2) I have copy all contains from basic "home" and paste in "home2"

3) Then I go to Stores >> Configuration >> Web >>Default pages

4) Switch to English store Website and select new created page "home2".

5) After save and clean cache on English store view Homepage no displayed.

> [2018-08-03 11:00:41] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: btn btn-default {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid block type: btn btn-default at vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:275, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class btn btn-default does not exist at vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []

Comment: you can create a new page and assign to respect store, or do you want different layouts for each store ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your different homepages in `admin>Pages`
2. Set the right homepage for each storeview in `Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page`, change first the storeview scope in top left corner (Store View:  Default Config), then in `Default Page` unckech `Use system value` and select your homepage from the dropdown list then save.
3. Clean the cache.

[image]

Comment: I updated my topic.

Comment: Also specify to switch to the required store from the dropdown available on the left